# Why I can't add items to the Generic List with indexer?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, generics

Here is a strange situation I have seen today:

I have a generic list and I want add items to my list with it's indexer like this:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>(10);
myList[0] = "bla bla bla...";
```

When I try this, I'm getting `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

[image]

Then I looked at `List<T>` indexer set method, and here it is:

```
[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries"),    __DynamicallyInvokable] 
  set
  {
    if ((uint) index >= (uint) this._size)  
      ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException();  //here is exception
    this._items[index] = value;
    ++this._version;
  }
```

And also looked at `Add` method:

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public void Add(T item)
{
  if (this._size == this._items.Length)
    this.EnsureCapacity(this._size + 1);
  this._items[this._size++] = item;
  ++this._version;
}
```

Now, as I see both methods are using the same way:

```
// Add() Method
this._items[this._size++] = item; 
// Setter method
this._items[index] = value;
```

The `_items` is an array of type `T` :

```
private T[] _items;
```

And in the constructor `_items` initialized like this:

```
this._items = new T[capacity]
```

Now, after all of these I'm curious about why I can't add items into my list with an index
,although I specify list capacity explicitly?

Comment: The indexer does NOT add items. You have an empty list and you are trying to access the (non-existent) first item

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason is that you don't *add* to the list with the indexer, you *replace existing items*.

Since you have not yet added any items to the list, it is empty, and any attempt at using the indexer to "add" items to it will throw that exception.

This:

```
new List<string>(11);
```

does not create a list with 11 elements, it creates a list with capacity for 11 elements initially. This is an optimization. If you add more elements, the list will have to be resized internally, and you can pass in the expected or known capacity to avoid too many of those resizes.

Here's a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates:

```
void Main()
{
    var l = new List<string>(10);
    l.Dump(); // empty list

    l.Add("Item");
    l.Dump(); // one item

    l[0] = "Other item";
    l.Dump(); // still one item

    l.Capacity.Dump(); // should be 10
    l.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(idx => idx.ToString()));
    l.Capacity.Dump(); // should be 21 or more
}
```

Output:

[image: output of linqpad program]

---

**Internals**

Internally, inside a `List<T>`, an array is actually used to hold the elements. Additionally, a `Count` property/value is kept to keep track of how many of those array elements have actually been used.

When you construct an empty list, not passing in a capacity, a default one is used, and this is the initial size of that array.

As you keep adding new elements to the list, slowly you will fill up that array, towards the end. Once you have filled the entire array, and add another element to it, a new, bigger, array will have to be constructed. All the elements in the old array are then copied over to this new, bigger, array, and from now on, that array is used instead.

That is why the internal code calls that `EnsureCapacity` method. This method is the one doing the resize operation, if necessary.

Every time the array has to be resized, a new array is constructed and all the elements copied over. As the array grows, this operation grows in cost. It's not *all* that much, but it still isn't free.

That is why, if you know that you will need to store, say, 1000 elements in the list, it is a good idea to pass in a capacity value to begin with. That way, the initial size of that array might be large enough to never need to be resized/replaced. At the same time, it's not a good idea to just pass in a very large value for capacity, as this might end up using a lot of memory unnecessary.

Also know that everything in this section of the answer is undocumented (as far as I know) behavior, and should any details or specific behavior you might learn from it should never influence the code you write, other than the knowledge about passing in a good capacity value.

Comment: Moreover, there is an `Insert` method which is using the index but is throwing the same exception is the list items have not been "initialized" with a fake value.

Comment: You can call `Insert` on an empty list, passing in index 0. It will basically amount to the same thing as `Add`. That is, you can pass in `Count` and it'll work.

Comment: Absolutely. But if he tries to do `Insert(5, "item")`, it will throw the exception.

Comment: Thanks, but still i don't know what is the point of setter method in that indexer ? because Add method doesn't use setter method, if i can't use why it is exist ??

Comment: You can use it *after* you have added an element to the list. Try: `list.Add("Test"); list[0] = "Other test";`

Comment: Now I understand, thank you all :) As a result: we can't use indexer to add a new element into a generic list but we can use it to change existing elements.

Answer (score 7):

No, it's not strange. You are mistakenly assuming the constructor that accepts capacity initializes that many elements in the list. It does not. The list is empty and you must add elements.

If for some reason you need to initialize it with elements, you could do this:

```
 new List<string>(Enumerable.Repeat<string>(string.Empty, 11));
```

Sounds like a `string[]` array is a better fit though.

Comment: Then, how can i set the size ? or if i can't why there is a setter method in that indexer ?

Comment: The capacity is all about avoiding memory reallocation. Set the appropriate capacity and just use add. Or if you must initialize with a load a null entries.

Answer (score 6):

Strange or not. It is documented: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Exception: ArgumentOutOfRangeException
index is less than 0.
-or-
index is equal to or greater than Count.
```

Answer (score 4):

There is difference between Capacity of the list and Count of the list.

Capacity says how big the internal array is big. Count says how many valid items the list contains. The constructor you are using is setting the capacity, but the amount of valid items is still 0. And the indexer checks against amount of valid items, not against capacity.