# List<string> to List<DateTime>

Tags: c#, methods, type-conversion

I have a method that returns a `List<DateTime>` but the code I run inside the method gives me a `List<string>`

How can I convert the `List<string>` to a `List<DateTime>` for my `return` line?

It's basically a method that takes in a List of photos and returns a List of their date's taken property;

```
            //retrieves the datetime WITHOUT loading the whole image
    public List<DateTime> GetDateTakenFromImage(List<string> path)
    {
        List<string> dateTaken = new List<string>();
        int cnt = 0;
        while (cnt < path.Count())
        {


            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path[cnt], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            using (Image myImage = Image.FromStream(fs, false, false))
            {

                PropertyItem propItem = myImage.GetPropertyItem(36867);
                dateTaken[cnt] = r.Replace(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(propItem.Value), "-", 2);
            }
            cnt++;
        }

        return dateTaken;
```

I got this code from the website so I'm not entirely sure if I can make it return them to a `List<DateTime>`

I think I can make the provided answers work for this code though.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably best to modify the inner code to produce a `DateTime` directly. Show us the code.

Comment: that code won't work (sorry it will compile but you will get an ArgumentOutOfRange exception in runtime),you are trying to add new items to the generic list with indexer : `dateTaken[cnt] = ...` but you can't, see my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840551/why-i-cant-add-items-to-the-generic-list-with-indexer)

Comment: @Selman22 thanks! I originally had a loop outside this method that just extracted each date taken prop one by one. But I was getting the ArgumentOutOfRange exception during runtime and had no idea why!!! I thought I could get around this by putting the loop inside the method

Comment: @teepee use Add method instead, `dateTaken.Add(...)`

Comment: @Selman22 Finally! thank you so much it worked, that was driving me nuts that I couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you know all the string's will parse properly as a DateTime, you can do something like:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>() { "2014-01-14" };

List<DateTime> dates = strings.Select(date => DateTime.Parse(date)).ToList();
```

Comment: +1 this is a more elegant solution than the one I had in mind.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the string is in the proper format:

```
List<DateTime> dateTimeList = new List<DateTime>();

foreach (string s in stringList)
    dateTimeList.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(s));

 return dateTimeList;
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx