# List to be accessible only with Enumeration

Tags: c#, list, enums

What would be the best way to make a `System.Collections.Generic.List` that should only be accessed by an `enum`? To help describe what I'm looking for, this how I'm doing it right now:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    First,
    Second,
    Count
}

class MyClass
{
    List<SomeClass> myList = new List<SomeClass>((int)MyEnum.Count);

    MyClass()
    {
        myList[(int)MyEnum.First] = new SomeClass(1);
        myList[(int)MyEnum.Second] = new SomeClass(2);
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something. Is there a better way of doing this? I'm sorry if the answer is obvious, I found it very difficult to search for something that sounded so generic.

---

As some background, I would be using this list to access different textures in my code, e.g. the `enum` would have texture names and each texture would be placed in and later accessed from the `List` using that texture name.

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<MyEnum,SomeClass>` instead?

Comment: Why not simply have three (or two) properties on `MyClass`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would it be possible to use `Dictionary` instead of `List`?

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<MyEnum, SomeClass>();
...
myDict[MyEnum.First] = new SomeClass(1);
myDict[MyEnum.Second] = new SomeClass(2);
```

Or, as @JimHurley suggested (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx) just

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<MyEnum, SomeClass>()
{
    { MyEnum.First, new SomeClass(1)},
    { MyEnum.Second, new SomeClass(2)}
};
```

Comment: I don't get the purpose of type `Dictionary<MyEnum, SomeClass>` at all, where `MyEnum` is just used to separate different objects. Why not just to use properties?

Comment: This way I can pass the Dictionary through a method as a parameter.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov For instance, to be able to enumerate all values in the dictionary.

Comment: @JimHurley can't say anything without some reasonable scenarios. Indeed you get behavior of a dictionary with max capacity of two pairs. But what about `myDict[MyEnum.Count] = new SomeClass(3);` - is this valid?

Comment: The `MyEnum.Count` was only necessary before to get the size of the list (a common practice of mine with arrays when I write in c++).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a new element to `List<T>` you have to use it's `Add` method.Indexer can be used *only* to modify existing items. I think in this case using a `Dictionary<MyEnum, SomeClass>` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Couldn't I use the indexer since I initialized the list with default values of the proper size? `List<SomeClass> myList = new List<SomeClass>((int)MyEnum.Count);`

Comment: @JimHurley no, because it just sets the capacity, it doesn't increase the count. see my [old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840551/why-i-cant-add-items-to-the-generic-list-with-indexer) and the answers for more information: